# Job description changed after hiring

Tags: job-offer, student

I am a robotics student in a work study program. While looking for the work part of the program, I received a message from the HR person of a company that I had not explicitly contacted after posting my CV on LinkedIn. There was no explicit job offer on their part to which I answered, I was just contacted out of the blue. I was invited to come in for an interview. During this interview, I was told that the company was looking for someone to work on robots for mostly pick and place applications.

This job description as it was presented to me was exactly what I was looking for, so I accepted. I have now been working at the company for 8 months, and have yet to see a robot. I have been put on an R&D project about database administration and data analysis. I don't  have any particular schooling on this subject. I have tried my best to get the job done to the best of my abilities, but I am really struggling to get the focus back on robotics.

This job is part of a work study program and I actually need the content to be related to my studies so that I can present my work at the end of the year. I feel like my bosses don't take me seriously because I am a student. They talk over me all the time and refuse to listen when I ask to be included in project that include robots. They say that data is very important in robotics etc, which it sure is, but I'd like to get robotics experience first, and then maybe go into data analysis once I'm done with my degree instead of, as they put it "getting ahead of the game", without getting basic experience in my main field of interest.

How can I get back on the right track working on the subject that was initially presented to me?

Comment: Have you discussed this with the school you're at?

Comment: Yes I have, but they're not very responsive. They seem to be pretty overwhelmed by the whole covid situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much you can do since it's a work study program. Usually the school places you or have a list of potential employers, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Whether they did or not you still need to keep pushing at the school because it may impact negatively on your end of year presentation. But that's not a given, because it would be pretty rare for a student to get the perfect job and any work related to the field may be all that is necessary. So it may be fine.

You can keep asking the workplace as well. But at the end of the day the difference is that you pay the school, whether they're having covid issues (still, after a year?) is not your problem, while the workplace pays you.